# Software for building non-overlapping sets of polygons?

Tags: google-maps, polygon

We have multiple populations of patients spread out over geographic distances.  For each population, we want users to easily define non-overlapping polygons.  The outer borders are likely to be U.S County boundaries, if that makes any difference.

Essentially, I'd like for users to visually build groups of non-overlapping polygons and have the application provide us with sets of coordinates for each polygon.  I would then be using the data in Google Maps.  We currently have a method to identify patient's location by lat/long, using Google Maps API if the user needs to approximate the location.

Web-based software is preferred, but I'd consider a desktop package if the interface was easy enough for our users with minimal training.

Comment: How do you currently store the patient data? It sounds like you need some type of spatial database.

Comment: Are you talking about building something like a [Voronoi diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram)

Comment: @celenius: updated the post to state that we're storing location by latitude/longitude.

Comment: @RyanDalton: A Voronoi diagram may be a mathematical explanation of what I'm trying to achieve, but from a user/use case perspective I'm looking for a means of constructing non-overlapping polygons and capturing the data as lat/long points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be to use [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) to enable users to draw polygons onscreen, and then to store these polygons in a postgresql/postigs database, transferring the data using the WFS-T protocol. I would avoid using the Google API directly as it does not easily facilitate analysis.

I don't quite understand what you mean by 'non-overlapping polygons'; do you want users not to draw over existing polygons?

Comment: Correct, I want adjoining polygons (polygons where the edges join), but do not want them placed over existing polygons.

Comment: That sounds like it might be easiest to check on the server side. A user can draw a polygon and then it could be submitted, then using PostGIS, the function ST_Intersect could see if there is any overlap.

Comment: The 'drawing tool' is what I'm looking for.  We're currently investigating OpenLayers to see if it can fit the bill.

Comment: You've probably seen this: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/draw-feature.html